# Getting '502 BAD Gateway' while uploading image using SAM local lambda function

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-serverless, bad-gateway, http-status-code-502

When uploading a image to a SAM local Lambda function,then it fails with a **502 BAD GATEWAY**.

Getting **502** error before calling Lambda function, Lambda code is not executed, no display any logs. It just getting 502 error response.

SAM local Lambda function call with below yaml template :

```
LambdaName:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function 
    Properties:
      Handler: Handler::handleRequest
      Runtime: java8
      Policies:
      - DynamoDBCrudPolicy:
          TableName: "*"
      - S3CrudPolicy:
          BucketName: "*"
      Events:
        EventName:
          Type: Api 
          Properties:
            ApiId: !Ref HttpApi
            Path: /demo
            Method: post 
            BinaryMediaTypes: [image/jpg]
```

Comment: You can turn on logging at the API Gateway level to see what's wrong. My guess is that your image is bigger than 6MB which is AWS Lambda's maximum payload limit.

Comment: No, my image size is less than 6MB.

Comment: What do you see from API Gateway logs?

Comment: Only return '502' without any logs

Comment: You have to turn on API Gateway logging. It is separate from Lambda logs.

Comment: Currently I am using SAM local lambda environment, so not able to turn on logging.